# Java reactor how to properly start async cancellable sideeffect

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I'm trying to write something using reactor which I know how to write using completable futures. I'm getting "Calling subscribe in non-blocking scope" warning in it.

My goal is to call `turnOn()` with a timeout which should call `turnOff()` after the timeout. If turnOn() is called again it should cancel the old timeout and wait for a new timeout.

How should I do this? I could do a hibrate and use CompletableFuture for the timeout but reactor's api is just a bit easier.

this test works as expected:

```
public class TimeoutTest {

    Service service;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        service = mock(Service.class);
    }

    CompletableFuture<Void> turnOffFuture = null;

    @DisplayName("Should timeout on turnOn with timeout")
    @Test
    public void timeoutCompletableFuture() throws InterruptedException {
        turnOn(Duration.ofMillis(100)).join();
        verify(service).turnOn();
        verify(service,never()).turnOff();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        verify(service).turnOff();
    }

    private interface Service{
        void turnOn();
        void turnOff();
    }

    public void cancelTimeout() {
        if (turnOffFuture != null)
            turnOffFuture.cancel(false);
        turnOffFuture = null;
    }

    public CompletableFuture<Void> turnOn(Duration timeout) {

        CompletableFuture<Void> turnOnFuture = turnOn();
        cancelTimeout();
        turnOffFuture = turnOnFuture.thenRun(() -> delay(timeout))
                                    .thenRun(this::turnOff);
        return turnOnFuture;
    }


    private void delay(Duration duration) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(BigDecimal.valueOf(duration.getSeconds())
                                   .scaleByPowerOfTen(3)
                                   .add(BigDecimal.valueOf(duration.getNano(), 6))
                                   .intValue());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private CompletableFuture<Void> turnOn() {
        return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> service.turnOn());
    }

    private CompletableFuture<Void> turnOff() {
        return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> service.turnOff());
    }
}
```

but my reactor code does not.

```
public class TimeoutMonoTest {

    Service service;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        service = mock(Service.class);
    }

    Disposable turnOffDisposable = null;

    @DisplayName("Should timeout on turnOn with timeout")
    @Test
    public void timeoutMono() throws InterruptedException {
        turnOn(Duration.ofMillis(100)).block(Duration.ofMillis(10));
        verify(service).turnOn();
        verify(service, never()).turnOff();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        verify(service).turnOff();
    }

    private interface Service {
        void turnOn();
        void turnOff();
    }

    public void cancelTimeout() {
        if (turnOffDisposable != null)
            turnOffDisposable.dispose();
        turnOffDisposable = null;
    }

    public Mono<Void> turnOn(Duration timeout) {

        Mono<Void> turnOnFuture = turnOn();
        cancelTimeout();
        turnOffDisposable = turnOnFuture.delayElement(timeout)
                                        .subscribe(it -> this.turnOff());
        return turnOnFuture;
    }


    private Mono<Void> turnOn() {
        service.turnOn();
        return Mono.just("not empty but mapped to void").then();
    }

    private Mono<Void> turnOff() {
        service.turnOff();
        return Mono.just("not empty but mapped to void").then();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in the mapping to void mono's in the `turnOn()` and `turnOff()` methods. They do not actually get a "next" signal, just a "success" signal.

The fix is simply to change the turnOn method to:

```
    public Mono<Void> turnOn(Duration timeout) {
        cancelTimeout();
        Mono<Void> turnOnMono = turnOn();
        turnOffDisposable = turnOnMono.delayElement(timeout)
                                      .then(turnOff())
                                      .subscribe();
        return turnOn();
    }
```